# OpenGL support in Solaris 10 x86

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, opengl

Our application supports Solaris Sparc and certain parts of it rely on OpenGL. I couldn't find the official guide on OpenGL support of Solaris x86. Any one has the respective information or related experience of OpenGL support in Solaris x86 (includes installing Solaris 10 to a normal PC, what kind of graphic cards support OpenGL in Solaris 10).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is available with Solaris on x86 either through MESA (software) or accelerated with an NVIDIA graphic card and its driver. Only Quadro cards used to be officially supported, I'm not sure about current status but it should work with most NVIDIA 3D cards. It is definitely does with my Geforce Go 6600TE/6200TE.

From var/log/Xorg.log:

```
(II) Loading extension NV-GLX
(II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA 3D Acceleration Architecture Initialized
```

http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

Comment: I'm fairly sure Solaris 10 and OpenSolaris also accelerate most of the Intel cards.

Comment: The i915 and radeon drivers are available on OpenSolaris. Not sure about Solaris 10 support though.

Comment: The link definitely help. At least NVIDIA has a Solaris forum with respective driver info and stating supported OpenGL version.

Comment: The 3D/drm drivers for i915 and radeon were never backported to Solaris 10 - only nvidia has accelerated OpenGL support on x86 in S10.